# how to show SQLite data in simpleadapter

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am facing an issue. i am trying to show sqlite data in the simple adapter but the data is not showing up in my application i don't know what is the wrong. i am new to android development need help.....

Here is my code

```
public class user extends AppCompatActivity {

    sqlite_database database;
    ListView listView;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arrayList;
    String stname,stfname,contact;
    HashMap<String, String> hmap;
    String n,f,c;
    TextView studentName, studentFatherName,studnetContact;
    Button show;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_user);

        database = new sqlite_database(getApplicationContext());
        listView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.userlistView);
        show = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnShoww);
        studentName = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.studentName);
        studentFatherName = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.studentFName);
        studnetContact = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.studentContact);

        studentName.setText(n);
        studentFatherName.setText(f);
        studnetContact.setText(c);


        ShowData();
        arrayList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
        try{

            Cursor c = database.showAllStudentData();


            while(c.moveToNext())
            {
                hmap= new HashMap<String, String>();
                stname=c.getString(0);
                hmap.put("n", stname);
                stfname=c.getString(1);
                hmap.put("f", stfname);
                contact=c.getString(2);
                hmap.put("c", contact);
                arrayList.add(hmap);

            }


        }
        catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("error",e.getMessage());

        }


        String from[]={n,f,c};


        int to[]={R.id.studentName,R.id.studentFName,R.id.studentContact};

        SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, arrayList, R.layout.user_info_layout, from, to);

        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    }


    public void ShowData()
    {
        show.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Cursor result = database.showAllStudentData();
                        if (result.getCount() == 0) {
                            //show Message
                            showMessage("Error", "Nothing is here");
                            return;
                        }
                        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
                        while (result.moveToNext()) {
                            buffer.append("Name: " + result.getString(0) + "\n");
                            buffer.append("Father Name: " + result.getString(1) + "\n");
                            buffer.append("Contact: " + result.getString(2) + "\n\n");
                        }
                        showMessage("Data", buffer.toString());
                    }
                }
        );
    }
    public void showMessage (String title, String message)
    {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setCancelable(true);
        builder.setTitle(title);
        builder.setMessage(message);
        builder.show();
    }

}
```

---

And this is my SQLite code

```
public Cursor showAllData()
    {
        SQLiteDatabase mydatabase = helper.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor result = mydatabase.rawQuery("select * from "+ Helper.TABLE_NAME,null);
        return result;
    }
```

layout....

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/userImage" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"></LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:id="@+id/studentName" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:id="@+id/studentFName" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:id="@+id/studentContact" />

</LinearLayout>
```

userActivity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.ks.doit.user">
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="#006700"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"></android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/userlistView"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Show All Data"
        android:id="@+id/btnShoww"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Your code is trying to populate a view with id `userListView`, but I don't see that anywhere in your layout.

Comment: it is in the mainactivity

Comment: Then perhaps you should show that layout as well.

Comment: <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/userlistView"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

Comment: Please show the entire layout formatted as code by editing your question and pasting it there.

Answer (score 0):

You should use CursorAdapter iа you're querying data from database for example:

```
            // columns
            final String[] columns = new String[] { "stname", "stfname, "contact" };
            // resource id's
            final int[] to = new int[] { R.id.studentName, R.id.studentFName, R.id.studentContact };

            // adapter
            final SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.student_layout, cursor, columns, to);

            // set adapter to listview
            listView.setListAdapter(mAdapter);
```

Comment: Are you sure that query is not empty? For example your "arrayList" is not empty?

Comment: It's a bad idea to transform cursor intro List and put it into SimpleAdapter. Because the point of cursor is not to load whole data at once, but fetch it with scrolling of ListView.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed it! It created a list of empty strings named **`from[]`**.

So, it should be like this:

```
String from[] = {"n", "f", "c"};
```